# DNN Platform: Is it possible to not log a specific IP address in the log files?

Tags: logging, dotnetnuke

DNN Platform: Is it possible to not log a specific IP address in the log files?  We have a load balance that pings the home site and it is creating a log every time it visits.  Also, we turned off the user online module because the purge visitor function was not working; an internal site which only a dozen people has access to was logging 500+ visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pinging the KeepAlive.aspx page?